# Java regular expression for a digit followed by z^3?

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string matches the form az^3 where a is any integer.
I've tried the following:

```
str.matches("\\d* z^3")

str.matches("\\d* z\^3")

str.matches("^(\\d* z^3)$")

str.matches("^(\\d* z\^3)$")

str.matches("\\d* (z^3)")

str.matches("\\d* (z\^3)")
```

This is driving me crazy. :-(
I've tried every possible regex tutorial and searched for examples and I still can't even come up with a solution.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in Java

```
str.matches("\\d+z\\^3");
```

Comment: Java regexes are never a simple solution... :P

Comment: @A_me Since it looks like this solved your problem, you should accept the answer.

Comment: @ajp15243: They are essentially the same as other languages (for the features that are common). Just that you need to mind the escaping and double the slash ``\`` up.

Comment: @nhahtdh I know they are pretty much feature complete when compared to other language regexes, but it would have been nice to not have to put "\\\\" just to detect a single "\" in your regex. It just looks ugly and reduces readability, which is already difficult enough with regexes.